# Write text from EditText to file - android

Tags: android, android-edittext, filewriter

I want to get the text from a EditText printed to a file. So when a user enters a message and hits the submit button, the message is written to the file.
Here's my code:

```
package com.getText.android;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class getText extends Activity {

public EditText ET;
public Button button1;
public String input;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    ET.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI); 

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClickMe);
    button1.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

}

private OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v){

        input = ET.getText().toString(); 

        try{

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fileOut.txt");

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));

        writer.write(input);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

}
```

The application runs just fine, but the file doesn't get created! Can someone tell me what's wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is necessary, but have you tried to do:

```
file.createNewFile();
```

before creating the `FileWriter`?

In general you should try to log your exceptions:

```
Log.e("getText", e.getMessage());
```

Unfortunately `e.printStackTrace()` won't make it into logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for permission to write to external storage

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html